# MemoryMappedViewStream.PointerOffset has wrong value

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

I'm having a little trouble understanding the [MemoryMappedViewStream.PointerOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewstream.pointeroffset(v=vs.110).aspx) property. In this simple unit test I would expect the PointerOffset of the stream to equal 500000 however it is 41248. The length of the stream is 10000 though, so that's correct at least. The _fakeDataPath is a file of 1 million bytes.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckViewHasCorrectOffset()
    {
        using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(_fakeDataPath))
        {
            using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream(500000, 10000))
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(500000, stream.PointerOffset);
            }
        }
    }
```

The unit test output is...

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<500000>. Actual:<41248>
```

Comment: The [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/IO/MemoryMappedFiles/MemoryMappedView.cs,91bd2847a1fb80e7) reveals what's going on: `PointerOffset` just returns what was passed into the private `MemoryMappedView` constructor and they are passing in `extraMemNeeded`, which a comment in the method says: "extraMemNeeded is the amount of extra memory we allocate before the start of the requested view", and is calculated as such `(ulong)offset % (ulong)MemoryMappedFile.GetSystemPageAllocationGranularity();`: 64k is common: `500000%(64*1024) = 41248`. Possibly a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CreateViewStream() is a .NET wrapper around the [MapViewOfFile() winapi function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx).  The most relevant detail of this api is:

> The combination of the high and low offsets must specify an offset within the file mapping. They must also match the memory allocation granularity of the system. That is, the offset must be a multiple of the allocation granularity.

The allocation granularity has been 64K forever.  Or to put it in another way, the native api demands that the offset you specify must always be a multiple of 65536.

That's pretty painful and they decided to hide that restriction in the .NET wrapper.  Easily done, they just need to pass a different offset to the native function so it starts at the closest aligned multiple of 65536 that's less than 500000.  And use a different internal offset so you get effectively still get 500000.  So you need to fix your code like this:

```
  Assert.AreEqual(500000 % 65536, stream.PointerOffset);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `PointerOffset` return `500000 - 500000%65536` instead? When requesting an offset at 500k bytes it has to actually request a multiple of 64k, which they pad the beginning to get there, so I would think the actual offset is the one shown in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/IO/MemoryMappedFiles/MemoryMappedView.cs): `ulong newOffset = (ulong)offset - extraMemNeeded;`. The view starts at byte 458,752 but `PointerOffset` is returning 41,248.

Comment: No, you assume newOffset will be the value of PointerOffset.  It is not, it is extraMemNeeded, look at the MemoryMappedView constructor call.  The OP's post also leaves little doubt.

Comment: I mean isn't it a bug that they are setting it to 41,248 (`extraMemNeeded` in source)? [`PointerOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewstream.pointeroffset(v=vs.110).aspx): "Gets the number of bytes by which the starting position of this view is offset from the beginning of the memory-mapped file". The view starts at `newOffset`, but then they assign `extraMemNeeded` to `PointerOffset`. I assume that newOffset *should* be PointerOffset and that they screwed up by passing in extraMemNeeded instead.

Comment: It makes sense to me, it is in fact the offset from the start of the native view.  Sloppy, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Does like a bug in the view - I've worked around the issue by tracking the view offsets independently. I'll try and find the correct forum to highlight the issue to Microsoft. Cheers.

Comment: I've highlighted the issue with the .NET Core team here...   https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/9528